# uninit_member: Non-static class member m_wszParams is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have IVerification class and this class has two member variables (m_wszParams and m_wszParamType). Here in this class constructor, I am not initializing these member variables. Later, initializing these variables in the derived class(MyReader).

Because of this I am getting the warning "uninit_member: Non-static class member m_wszParams is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls."

To resolve this warning, can I initialize these member variables with nullptr in the IVerification constructor like as shown below?

```
IVerification::IVerification()
{
    m_wszParams = nullptr;
    m_wszParamType = nullptr;
}
```

**Below is the complete code:**

**.h file**

```
class IVerification
{

public:
    IVerification();
    virtual ~IVerification(); 

protected:
    wchar_t* m_wszParams;
    wchar_t* m_wszParamType;
}
```

**.cpp file**

```
IVerification::IVerification()
{

}
```

**Below is the derived class**

**MyReader.h file**

```
class MyReader : public IVerification
{
public:
    MyReader();
    ~MyReader();
public:
    void SetParams(wchar_t* wszParams, wchar_t* wszParamType);
}
```

**MyReader.cpp file**

```
void MyReader::SetParams(wchar_t* wszParams, wchar_t* wszParamType)
{
    m_wszParamType = wszParamType;
    m_wszParams = wszParams;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225177/initializing-member-variables)

Comment: To initialize members with raw pointers (e.g. with `nullptr`) is a good idea in general, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum

```
class IVerification
{
public:
    IVerification() = default;
    virtual ~IVerification() = default;

protected:
    wchar_t* m_wszParams = nullptr;
    wchar_t* m_wszParamType = nullptr;
};
```

Next step: pointers are not your friends, use std::string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Instead of initializing the member variables when creating, can we initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder This is just a notation. They *are* initialised in the constructor. There is no separate creation step before the constructor.